# seq() function in R

Tags: r

I have a question about the `seq()` function in R. I am using the `sqldf` package to connect and wrap R code around sql select statements.

I need to run a script 10 times, where each time I select a specified number of rows (I'm creating a control cohort based in a frequency distribution) i.e. something like

```
SELECT * FROM table
LIMIT 2

SELECT * FROM table
LIMIT 4
```

and so on until

```
SELECT * FROM table
LIMIT i
```

where `i` is a sequence specified as `(2,4,6,8,10,12,10,9,7,3,1)`

but if I write:

`seq(2,4,6,8,10,12,10,9,7,3,1)` I am using too many arguments for the `seq()` function.

How do I get round this in R, as it's not like I want to increment from 1 to 10 in steps of 1 like `seq(1,10)`.

Hope I have made the question clear!

Comment: Are you by chance looking for `?c`?

Comment: Btw, you have now asked quite a few question on SO. One would expect that you are able to better format a question.

Comment: apologies - all my previous posts are - doing a 10 things at once this morning so not with it.

Comment: I was looking for a "how to define a vector" duplicate but ironically, no one has ever dared ask such a question.

Comment: I voted to close as too localized as I find unlikely that anyone brought here (especially given the title) will learn anything useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you have some misconceptions going on here.

`seq` generates a sequence of a a priori known pattern. You mentioned one example with `seq(from=1, to=10)`. Another version would be just to use multiples of two like

```
seq(from=2, to=10, by=2)
```

What you are doing is to write down your desired numbers hard-coded. Thus, you just could put them into a vector using `c` (which is probably the most basic R function I know of...)

```
c(2,4,6,8,10,12,10,9,7,3,1)
```

For further details, see `?seq` or `?c`.

Comment: +1 for "which is probably the most basic R function"

Comment: exactly what I was looking for - thanks. My background is in matlab and vectors are declared differently, but was asked to help someone out with R, which I have used only a few times (mainly to do survival curves).

Comment: @brucezepplin In that case I do have a good link for you: http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/octave-r.html - A basic translation between MATLAB and R. Not very deep, but helps with those basic problems.